# How can I define a variable in loop render html reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
render() {
return (
<ul>
{scopeOptions.map((option, keyOption) => (
    let myVar = keyOptions * 5
    <li key={keyOption}>
        <a href="#" data-value={option.value}>{option.label}</a>
    </li>
))}
</ul>
)
}
```

I want to define myVar variable in loop, but I don't know how to do it, please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return object inside map instead of implicit return.

Not sure If I am correct:-

1) `keyOptions` is not defined, did you mean `keyOption`

2) `data-value="{option.value}"`, I think it should be without double quotes

```
{scopeOptions.map((option, keyOption) => {
    let myVar = keyOption * 5
    return (
      <li key={keyOption}>
         <a href="#" data-value={option.value}>{option.label}</a>
      </li>
    )
})}
```

Working code below for reference:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let scopeOptions = [
      {
        'value': '1',
        'label': 'label 1'
      },
      {
        'value': '2',
        'label': 'label 2'
      }
    ]
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {scopeOptions.map((option, keyOption) => {
            let myVar = keyOption * 5;
            return (
              <li key={keyOption}>
                <a href="#something" data-value={option.value}>
                  {option.label}
                </a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: You are still returning implicitly returning from arrow function instead of this `((option, keyOption) => (` use this `((option, keyOption) => {`. Notice the brackets in the end.

Comment: I have also added working code below. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are using arrow function, create a block to define variable,
In order to write multiple statements inside your arrow function.

```
{scopeOptions.map((option, keyOption) => {
    let myVar = keyOption * 5
    return (<li key={keyOption}>
        <a href="#" data-value={option.value}>{option.label}</a>
    </li>)
})}
```

To learn more about arrow functions refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)